# Docker - Kill a detached docker with Ctrl+C inside container

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which I start in detached mode:

`docker-compose up -d #Container starts in background`

After that I start a few other services inside the container and then I enter the container's bash:

```
docker exec -it web bash  -c 'start_other_background_services.sh; bash;'
```

If I `Ctrl+C` while being inside the container's bash, the bash exits, but the docker container is still running since it was launched in detached mode.

My question is, while being in container's bash, is it possible to stop the already running detached container, once `Ctrl+C` is pressed?

I've tried catching the signal but it doesn't seem to work:

```
docker exec -it web bash  -c 'trap "echo ttteeeeeeeeeeeeest; exit 1" INT; start_other_background_services.sh; bash;'
```

If the above worked, I'd then try to find the entry point's PID and kill it

Comment: In normal use you shouldn't need `docker exec`.  A container doesn't normally run background processes, and a better setup would be to start a separate container for each process.  If you need to stop the container, `docker-compose stop` is the way to do it.  (The main container process's process ID is 1, and by normal Unix rules you can't kill(2) it.)

Comment: PID of ENTRYPOINT command is 1 for exec form, not sure if it would be possible to kill it.

Comment: I believe the issue with PID 1 of the ENTRYPOINT can be solved by using the init flag : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process